# Need scaling in tikz to get actual 1:1 ratio

Tags: tikz-pgf

For some reason when I try to output a pdf which really gives a 1:1 scale when printed I need to add some strange scaling. For example, the code below gives me a millimeter-grid which (when printed and measured with a ruler) is actually correct. Why do I need those strange scalings?

```
\documentclass[class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.0465, yscale = 1.039]
% size (in mm) x:-10 to 110 
%       y:0 to 240
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xm}{-10};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xs}{\xm +1};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xM}{110};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ym}{0};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ys}{\ym +1};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yM}{240};
\foreach \i in {\xm,\xs,...,\xM} {
    \draw[gray,very thin] (\i/10,\ym/10) -- (\i/10,\yM/10);
    }
\foreach \i in {\ym,\ys,...,\yM} {
    \draw[gray,very thin] (\xm/10,\i/10) -- (\xM/10,\i/10);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the scaling and add dimensions to your coordinates for example `\xM mm`

Comment: You need `\end{tikzpicture}` to get anything, I think. However, the issue is with the units, as percusse says. `+1` *what*? You don't say, so Ti*k*Z has to guess/fallback..

Comment: Although the default is `cm` ... usually. If I typeset your example as-is, the PDF is 129mm by 249mm. If I remove the scaling, it is 120mm by 240mm. So the PDF size appears to be correct. What does your PDF viewr have to say about the dimensions?

Comment: How do you print it? Output format? Viewer/print program? Print options?

Comment: BTW, a shorter way to draw the grid: `\tikz\draw[gray, very thin] (-1, 0) grid[step=.1] (11, 24);`

Comment: @percusse: the mm or cm option does not change anything. I can ask tikz to write 1 cm, but it is still shorter than 1 cm (on paper).

Comment: Then your printer is scaling or your viewer is set to *fit to page width*

Comment: @cfr: sorry for the \end{tikzpicture} forgot to correct it... It does not matter where I print (i.e. from work or at home). Using Okular as a pdf viewer. And there are not a lot of printing options (no zoom or fit).

Comment: What does Okular say the *dimensions* are? Without the scaling, Okular tells me they are 120x240mm. With scaling, 129x249mm. If the PDF dimensions are correct, but the printed version isn't, then it is being scaled by the print process - but that has nothing to do with TeX.

Comment: @ARG What happens if it is printed with different PDF viewers?

Comment: Okular tells me the paper size is 4.94683 x 9.8201 in (that's 12.5649482 x 24.943054 cm). This indeed shows that the distortion is not there. It's still strange because I did try out with different printers (from diffrente company) as well as different OS, and this scaling turned out to be always correct... The problem is probably tex unrelated as many of you pointed out/hinted at.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment.

If you tried to compile this

```
\pdfminorversion=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \fill(0,0)rectangle(5in,5in);
    \fill[white](.5in,.5in)rectangle(4.5in,4.5in);
}
\end{document}
```

and look into the PDF file, you will see

```
0.0 0.0 m 
0.0 360.00462 l 
360.00462 360.00462 l 
360.00462 0.0 l 
h 
360.00462 360.00462 m 
f
```

That basically means

```
move to (0,0)
draw a line to (0,360)
draw a line to (360,360)
draw a line to (360,0)
draw a line to the starting point, i.e. (0,0)
move to (360,360)
fill the preceding path
```

Here `360` means 360`bp`, or 360 PostScript-Points, which is **exactly** 5 inches or **exactly** 12.7 centimeters.

360.00462`bp` is larger than 360`bp` by 1630 nanometers. That is less than three times the wavelength of the red light. So it should not make any visible difference.

If I were you, I will try to print this square to see if it comes out as an exact square. If not, sue the printer company.

Comment: very funny and instructive, thanks! My problem is that I tried this with different printers (and on different operating systems), and the file with scaling was always in agreement with my ruler, whereas the file without, was not...

Comment: @ARG It might be the case the paper is too thick (or thin) so there is an offset when printer is moving the paper. It can also be the case that your ruler is not accurate. But you can still tell whether a square is perfect without a ruler---just fold the paper. Thus I would like to test whether this square is perfect before I measure the exact side length.

Comment: Let us assume that with `xscale=1.0465,yscale=1.039` your printer prints perfect square. Then without scaling the aspect of printed rectangle will be 1.0465/1.039 ≈ 1.007218. If the rectangle is 5 inches wide then it should have height 5 inches plus 0.916 millimeter. And that will be a visible difference.

Comment: thanks, there seems to be a random distortion from page to page (so actually the "square" has about 1 mm difference on its diagonals and less than a half millimiter on its opposite sides). What bugs me is that I need the scaling at all...but this problem seems to be independent from Tex.